# negating a custom unittest in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I've written a custom assertion to test if two lists of objects contain objects with the same attributes, and now I want to use the negation of the test to check if two lists are unequal.

```
from unittest import TestCase
from classes import *

class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    def assertCountObjectsEqual(self, list1, list2):
        if len(list1) != len(list2):
            raise AssertionError("lists must be the same length")
        elif any(t1.__class__ != t2.__class__ or t1.__dict__ != t2.__dict__ for t1, t2 in zip(list1, list2)):
            raise AssertionError("objects are not the same")
        else:
            pass
```

The positive case works

```
class TestFillDemand(BaseTestCase):
    def test_fruit(self):
        self.assertCountObjectsEqual([Apple(), Apple(), Banana()], [Apple(), Apple(), Banana()])
```

But I want to be able to reuse the code for something like the following:

```
    def test_fruit_unequal(self):
        self.assertRaises(AssertionError, self.assertCountObjectsEqual([Apple(), Apple(), Banana()], [Apple(), Banana()]))
```

rather than having to redefine an `assertCountObjectsUnequal` method. Unfortunately the above code doesn't work.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to wrap your list of objects into a custom "Collection" class defining the [`__eq__()` magic method](http://minhhh.github.io/posts/a-guide-to-pythons-magic-methods#comparison-magic-methods). This way, you will be able to utilize built-in assertion methods - `assertEqual()` and `assertNotEqual()`:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class Apple:
    pass


class Banana:
    pass


class Collection:
    def __init__(self, objects):
        self.objects = objects

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if len(self.objects) != len(other.objects):
            return False
        if any(t1.__class__ != t2.__class__ or t1.__dict__ != t2.__dict__ for t1, t2 in zip(self.objects, other.objects)):
            return False

        return True


class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_fruit_equal(self):
        self.assertEqual(Collection([Apple(), Apple(), Banana()]), Collection([Apple(), Apple(), Banana()]))

    def test_fruit_unequal(self):
        self.assertNotEqual(Collection([Apple(), Apple(), Banana()]), Collection([Apple(), Banana()]))
```

Both tests pass.

Comment: This works, but I guess I wanted to know whether there was a way to negate a test, without having to define the "Not" version separately.